# How can i specify a NotebookSelection by a given CellObject?

Tags: notebooks, cells

My Questing is very simple. If I have a `CellObject` e.g. `CellObject[Text]`, I can move the selection to this `Cell` by just clicking inside of this `CellObject`.

How can I programmatically move the selection to this `CellObject`? In other words, how can i trigger this internal `"MoveSelectionToCellObject"` - token  from Code?

I make an example:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["1", "Text"], TextCell["2", "Text"]}]
firstCell = Cells[nb]〚1〛
(* move Selection in nb to firstCell *)
```

I know there is a function `SelectionMove` but it seams to move the Selection only relative to some units like cells, but i want to be able to select a specific cell by a `CellObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectionMove` works on `CellObjects` just like on `NotebookObjects`:

```
SelectionMove[Cells[nb][[1]], All, Cell]
```

Comment: Nice! From the documentation of `SelectionMove` it was really not clear to me, that one could do that. All examples where exclusivly with `NotebookObject` and the usage text: "moves the current selection in an open notebook in the front end in the direction dir by the specified unit. " did not made it clear for me, that the object could also be a `Cell`. Well I just started with this kind of notebookmanipulation, but i think just one example in the documentation about a `CellObject` would be nice. By the way, thank you for correcting my english :)

Comment: @sacratus notebook programming is fun, good luck. meanwhile, please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)